# Роль слова "сам" в выражении "сам не знаю"

Tags: словоупотребление

Есть ли разница между "Я еще не знаю" и "Я еще сам не знаю", или эти два выражения означают одно и то же?

Comment: второе предложение с речевой ошибкой. нельзя употреблять я и сам в одном контексте и месте одновремнно

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Такое выражение подразумевает: я *первый*, кто должен был об этом узнать, но **даже я** ещё не знаю (не говоря о ком-либо другом).

Answer (score 1):

По идее есть. **`Я еще сам не знаю`** подразумевает, что кроме говорящего не знает ещё кто-то, например его собеседник, задающий вопрос, что говорит о его незнании, или какие-то другие люди, которые, как предполагается, должны бы знать.